# Dynamically Change tooltip text (tippy.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am using tippy.js to generate tooltips in an asp.net mvc application.
I am trying to change the text of the tooltip dynamically depending on another element, a drop down list. The problem I have is that the 'old' tooltips show on top of each other.

Here is my code (simplified):

```
$(document).on('change', '.partyStatus', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation(); //stops propagation of click event to other element having the same ID

    if (this.value == 5) //Visitor => no autocomplete: free text...
    {
        partyNameInput.className = "form-control partyName tip";         
        partyNameInput.title = "Please enter the visitor name.";
        tooltip('.tip', 'ehs');
    }
    else {
        partyNameInput.className = "form-control autocomplete_party partyName tip";
        partyNameInput.title = "Type in the first letter of a surname, and pick the person from the list.";

        tooltip('.tip', 'ehs');
    }

});
```

The tooltip function:

```
function tooltip(selector, userTheme) {
    tippy(selector, {
        theme: userTheme,
        position: 'right',
        animation: 'scale',
        duration: 600
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set the dynamicTitle option to true.

```
tippy(selector, {
  theme: userTheme,
  position: 'right',
  animation: scale,
  dynamicTitle: true
})
```

Then you can change the title attribute of the element onClick or onHover

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.setAttribute('title', 'New tooltip title here!');
})
```

Source TippyJS docs: https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/

Comment: Using Tippy v5.1.2 and `dynamicTitle` is no longer an option... having trouble finding the alternative

Answer (score 1):

For Tippy v6 it's stated in the documentation on how you could 1) [get the tippy property](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/tippy-instance/#-property) and 2) [how to set the content](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/methods/#setcontent).

For example, let's display 'Hide' when the the element has the class 'active', and display 'Show' when the it doesn't have the 'active' class:

```
$(document).on('click', '.filter', function (){
    if( $(this).hasClass('active') ){
        this._tippy.setContent('Hide')
    }else{
        this._tippy.setContent('Show');
    }
})
```